# Drawing SVG in <canvas>: simplest way to do it?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, drawimage

I'm attempting to draw an SVG image on a canvas element. Some sources I found suggest I should use a special library to convert SVG data to `<canvas>` strokes, while others say that I can just use the `drawImage()` call on a canvas with the SVG image to draw it.

First I used the `canvg` library to draw my SVG on the canvas, but I figured that it was much too feature rich and much too heavy for my simple needs. However, using a simple `drawImage` call does not seem to work in my application: nothing is displayed whatsoever. If I switch out the rescource URL of my SVG with a PNG image it displays just fine. What is wrong? Could I be doing anything wrong or is drawing SVG on canvas not supported in this way anymore?

I've tried this in Chrome 21, 22-canary and Opera.

My code (in CoffeeScript):

```
ctx = @canvas.getContext '2d'
ctx.clearRect 0, 0, @canvas.width, @canvas.height
ctx.drawImg @image, 0, 0, @canvas.width, @canvas.height
```

Works if `@image` points to a PNG, not if SVG.

Comment: No example == not possible to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It's trivial, but I've updated my question. Canvas on page, get canvas 2d context, call drawImage. As stated, this setup works with bitmaps, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my code. I'm wondering if this sort of thing is supported at all in the latest browsers.

Comment: If the image is fully loaded before the drawImage call that looks like it should work, assuming the svg file is correct.